# How to find the multiple keys in multiple JSON and Return only those rows that are having some value in postgresql9.5

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have table with multiple JSON rows. In this JSON structure stored different different key value like as :

```
"official_form_attributes":{"81459" : "Y", "81460" : " ", "81293" : "1~Yes", "80985" : " ", "80953" : "1", "80952" : " ", "80951" : "8~Forward", "81291" : "1~Yes", "81295" : "1~Yes", "81294" : "1~Yes", "80986" : "1~PRED", "81292" : "1~Yes", "80954" : "4", "80950" : " "}
```

```
"official_form_attributes":{"81321" : "6", "81315" : "15/06/2020", "81364" : "Approved", "81320" : "100000", "81466" : " ", "81314" : "1~Pucca", "80958" : "9~Forward to Tahsildar", "81318" : "20", "81325" : "20", "81465" : "Y", "81322" : "20000", "81324" : "1~Partially Damaged", "81323" : "20000", "81317" : "30", "81326" : "5200", "81319" : "600", "81316" : " "}
```

```
"official_form_attributes":{"82817" : " ", "82818" : " ", "82835" : "4", "81486" : "1~Yes", "82855" : "4", "83240" : "29/10950004/2020/07/09/29006271/10950004_9356416_3914_1594303859111.pdf", "81487" : " ", "80963" : "approved", "81488" : "5200", "80962" : "11~Approve by Tahsildar"}.
```

I have to find the key in this table. the result of that query is return all rows with some value and null value regarding this key.
But my requirement is that return only those rows which have some value that key.

CASE 1
MY query

```sql
select application_id, current_process_id, processing_json->'official_form_attributes'->'81488' 
from schm_ka.processing_data_json 
where application_id = 9356416;
```

Result:

```
applid      keyvalue
9356416     ""
9356416     ""
9356416     "5200"
```

But I need only this

```
applid      keyvalue
9356416     "5200"
```

CASE 2

```
select application_id, current_process_id, processing_json->'official_form_attributes'->'81488',processing_json->'official_form_attributes'->'81315' 
from schm_ka.processing_data_json 
where application_id = 9356416;
```

Result

```
applid  key1value   key2value
9356416     ""          ""
9356416     ""          "15/06/2020"
9356416     "5200"      ""
```

But I need only this

```
applid      key1value   key2value
9356416     "5200"      "15/06/2020"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For case 1, just put it into the WHERE clause:

```
select application_id, 
       processing_json->'official_form_attributes' ->> '81488' 
from schm_ka.processing_data_json 
where application_id = 9356416
  and processing_json -> 'official_form_attributes' ? '81488';
```

The `?` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) tests if a key is present in the JSON value

For case 2 you need aggregation:

```
select application_id, 
       max(processing_json->'official_form_attributes'->>'81488') as key_value_1,
       max(processing_json->'official_form_attributes'->>'81315') as key_value_2 
from schm_ka.processing_data_json 
where application_id = 9356416
  and processing_json->'official_form_attributes' ?| array['81488', '81315']
group by application_id;
```

The `?|` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) tests if any of the provided keys in the array is present in the JSON value. As you apparently get multiple rows with that condition, the aggregation is needed to collapse them into one row.